# Why is TestNG not running tests with DataProvider?

Tags: testng, maven-3

I'm having a weird issue I can't figure out. It's driving me insane.

I have a Maven project for which I'm running the same command both locally and on Jenkins. The environment is the same as far as I can tell:

- Maven 3.9.2 (On Jenkins: Docker image maven:3.9.2-eclipse-temurin-11)
- JDK 11 (On Jenkins: Docker image maven:3.9.2-eclipse-temurin-11)
- TestNG 7.8.0

Command:

```
mvn -Ddependency.surefire.verbose=10 -Pcoverage verify -B -U
```

Relevant POM section:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.10</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
...
</build>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>coverage</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>com/XXX/framework/dataproviders/**/*</exclude>
                <exclude>com/XXX/v2/basetest/**/*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*Exception*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
              <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <!-- Add this checking -->
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-check</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <rules>
                    <rule>
                      <element>BUNDLE</element>
                      <limits>
                        <limit>
                          <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                          <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                          <minimum>60%</minimum>
                        </limit>
                        <limit>
                          <counter>CLASS</counter>
                          <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                          <maximum>0</maximum>
                        </limit>
                      </limits>
                    </rule>
                    <rule>
                      <element>PACKAGE</element>
                      <limits>
                        <limit>
                          <counter>LINE</counter>
                          <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                          <minimum>60%</minimum>
                        </limit>
                      </limits>
                    </rule>
                  </rules>
                  <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

One of the tests that have the issue (only tests with DataProviders) shows this pattern in the logs. Enabled verbose to level 10 in hopes that something would show up.

Locally:

```
[2023-06-06 16:55:46.795] [INFO] [TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest]
[2023-06-06 16:55:46.796] [INFO] Method public java.lang.Object[][] com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest.getTimeData() has a @Test annotation but also a return value: ignoring it. Use <suite allow-return-values="true"> to fix this
[2023-06-06 16:55:46.797] [INFO] [TestClass] Adding method TimeUtilsTest.testToFormattedString(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,int,java.lang.String,com.XXX.framework.annotations.TestNameParameter)[pri:0, instance:null] on TestClass class com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest
```

...

```
[2023-06-06 16:55:47.316] [INFO] ===== Test class
com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest
[2023-06-06 16:55:47.316] [INFO]     @Test TimeUtilsTest.testToFormattedString(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,int,java.lang.String,com.XXX.framework.annotations.TestNameParameter)[pri:0, instance:com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest@283eb984]
[2023-06-06 16:55:47.316] [INFO] ======
```

...

```
[TestNG] INVOKING: "Surefire test" - com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest.testToFormattedString(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,int,java.lang.String,com.XXX.framework.annotations.TestNameParameter)(value(s): NANOSECONDS, 60, "60ns", TestNameParameter(customName=60 NANOSECONDS))
```

...
Test executes and results, etc.

On Jenkins:

```
[2023-06-06 21:02:29.270] [INFO] [TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest]
[2023-06-06 21:02:29.271] [INFO] Method public java.lang.Object[][] com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest.getTimeData() has a @Test annotation but also a return value: ignoring it. Use <suite allow-return-values="true"> to fix this
[2023-06-06 21:02:29.271] [INFO] [TestClass] Adding method TimeUtilsTest.testToFormattedString(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,int,java.lang.String,com.XXX.framework.annotations.TestNameParameter)[pri:0, instance:null] on TestClass class com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest
```

...

```
[2023-06-06 21:02:29.529] [INFO] ===== Test class
com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest
[2023-06-06 21:02:29.529] [INFO]     @Test TimeUtilsTest.testToFormattedString(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,int,java.lang.String,com.XXX.framework.annotations.TestNameParameter)[pri:0, instance:com.XXX.framework.utils.TimeUtilsTest@52f9a620]
[2023-06-06 21:02:29.529] [INFO] ======
```

I see no other references about the test class in the rest of the trace. Basically, all tests with a DataProvider don't run.

Maybe someone has a suggestion on what else to look for.

I've tried the following:

- Making sure the right Test annotation is used (TestNG vs. JUnit
- Remove test groups or any other listener that could be interfering.
- Downgrade the TestNG version.
- Pray.

Comment: You have  `<skip>${skipTests}` in `<goal>check`. Are you sure that this isn't set to `true` in the Jenkins build?

Comment: Yes, it is false by default. Other tests are running, just not the ones with DataProvider and only on Jenkins. Run fine locally.

Comment: If I add a dummy test on the skipped classes it'll run as long as it has no DataProviders.

Comment: I did some investigation with TestNG team and seems to be somehow related to surefire as logging proved the test is added but surefire just doesn't invoke the test. https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/2924

Comment: Created issue in surefire side in hopes to get some ideas: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-2180

Comment: In a coincidenceI I recently learned here at SO that Surefire seems to be a bit picky regarding the (correct–at least what it "thinks" is the correct) version of the test framework dependencies declared in the POM. See the very end of my answer to [_Java unit test run successfully on Intellij but fail on maven_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76426292/1744774). Perhaps something similar applies to your issue as well.

Comment: What's the exact Surefire version you are using?

Comment: please add the required information as I commented on the SUREFIRE issue ... without surefire/failsafe plugin version, Maven version, POM file, the test code etc. it's impossible to say what might be wrong?

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the sample test data provider you posted in the Surefire ticket had `parallel = true` set. Does the issue still persist when you switch to `false`?

Comment: Creating issues in two projects and a bounty question on Stack Overflow, but failing to provide a reproducer anywhere, is kind of a waste. Instead, you published a GitHub project **not** reproducing the problem, whatever that is meant to be good for. Maybe ask a better question in order to get better answers.

Comment: I'm looking for help to find the root cause. Obviously, I can't reproduce outside my project, so it is not TestNG or Surefire-specific issue. I suspect it is an edge case with dependencies. is hard to make a more specific question when the cause is not found yet.

Comment: Just copy your whole project, then step by step strip off as much as you can, until you arrive at the minimum setup which still reproduces the problem. Then anonymise package and class names and post it on GitHub as a reproducer. Chances are, that while stripping down the project you might understand more about the root cause and finally do not even need to ask anymore. It often happens like that. But even if you still do need help, I am pretty sure you will get it here. I am ready to help, but I need something to work with. Sorry that it is no easier than that, but this is what developers do.

Comment: That's the same conclusion I arrived at. Will create a new project from scratch and transfer piece by piece. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, my suggestion was exactly the other way around: Do not start from scratch and **add** stuff, but use your current project (which already reproduces the problem) and **remove** stuff. That is way easier in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a bit convoluted but neither TestNG nor Sunfire were at fault. It was a mix of a custom TestNG listener skipping the test but not logging when it did. The test was being skipped due to another test injecting a parameter in the environment that was causing the listener to skip the test.

Once the test cleaned properly the environment when done the issue went away.