# Java unit test run successfully on Intellij but fail on maven

Tags: java, maven

I am facing an issue that the unit test cases pass on IntelliJ but fail on `mvn test` command. I think the problem is about java 17 but I'm not sure. Src code can be found [here](https://github.com/anaconda875/udacity-webcrawler)

Maven version (with jdk 17):

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: D:\Apps\maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: D:\Program Files\jdk17\app
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1258
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.truth/truth -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
        <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    com.udacity.webcrawler.main.WebCrawlerMain
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>testDataDir</name>
                        <value>${project.basedir}/src/test/data</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>crawlerImplementations</name>
                        <value>
                            com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler
                            com.udacity.webcrawler.ParallelWebCrawler
                        </value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the code:

```
public final class ProfilerImplTest {
    private final FakeClock clock = new FakeClock();
    private final Profiler profiler = new ProfilerImpl(clock, true);
    private final ProfiledInterfaceImpl delegate = new ProfiledInterfaceImpl(clock);

    @Test
    public void delegateHasNoMethodsAnnotated() {
        assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> profiler.wrap(NonProfiledInterface.class, new NonProfiledInterfaceImpl()),
                "Profiler.wrap() should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the wrapped interface does " +
                        "not contain a @Profiled method.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        ProfiledInterface proxy = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);

        assertWithMessage("The proxy should delegate toString() calls to the wrapped object.")
                .that(proxy.toString())
                .isEqualTo(delegate.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHashCode() {
        ProfiledInterface proxy = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);

        assertWithMessage("The proxy should delegate hashCode() calls to the wrapped object.")
                .that(proxy.hashCode())
                .isEqualTo(delegate.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals() {
        ProfiledInterface proxy1 = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);
        ProfiledInterface proxy2 = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);

        assertThat(proxy1).isNotSameInstanceAs(delegate);
        assertThat(proxy1).isEqualTo(delegate);
        assertThat(delegate).isEqualTo(proxy1);

        assertWithMessage("Each call to Profiler.wrap() should create a new proxy object.")
                .that(proxy1)
                .isNotSameInstanceAs(proxy2);
        assertWithMessage("Two proxies should be equal if their wrapped objects are equal")
                .that(proxy1)
                .isEqualTo(proxy2);
        assertWithMessage("Two proxies should be equal if their wrapped objects are equal")
                .that(proxy2)
                .isEqualTo(proxy1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNonObjectEquals() {
        ProfiledInterface proxy = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);

        assertWithMessage("Incorrect equals() method was called")
                .that(proxy.equals("foo", "bar"))
                .isFalse();

        assertThat(delegate.wasFakeEqualsCalled()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasicProfiling() throws Exception {
        ProfiledInterface proxy = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);

        Instant beforeInvocation = clock.instant();

        assertWithMessage("The intercepted method did not forward the return value correctly")
                .that(proxy.profiled())
                .isEqualTo("profiled");
        Instant afterInvocation = clock.instant();
        assertWithMessage("Expected time to advance from invocation.")
                .that(beforeInvocation)
                .isLessThan(afterInvocation);

        // Run the method again a few more times to aggregate some data.
        proxy.profiled();
        proxy.profiled();

        CloseableStringWriter writer = new CloseableStringWriter();
        profiler.writeData(writer);
        assertWithMessage("Streams should usually be closed in the same scope where they were created")
                .that(writer.isClosed())
                .isFalse();
        String written = writer.toString();
        assertWithMessage("The profile data was not written or is incorrect")
                .that(written)
                .contains(
                        "com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImplTest$ProfiledInterfaceImpl#profiled");
        assertThat(written).contains("0m 3s 0ms");
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeclaredExceptionHandling() throws Exception {
        ProfiledInterface proxy = profiler.wrap(ProfiledInterface.class, delegate);

        Instant beforeInvocation = clock.instant();
        Throwable expected = assertThrows(
                Throwable.class,
                () -> proxy.throwSomething(new Throwable("expected exception")),
                "The method interceptor should forward exceptions thrown by the wrapped object");
        assertWithMessage("The proxy threw a different exception than was thrown by the wrapped object")
                .that(expected)
                .hasMessageThat()
                .isEqualTo("expected exception");

        Instant afterInvocation = clock.instant();
        assertWithMessage("Expected time to advance from invocation.")
                .that(beforeInvocation)
                .isLessThan(afterInvocation);

        CloseableStringWriter writer = new CloseableStringWriter();
        profiler.writeData(writer);
        assertWithMessage("Streams should usually be closed in the same scope where they were created")
                .that(writer.isClosed())
                .isFalse();
        String written = writer.toString();
        assertWithMessage("Profile data should still be recorded if an exception was thrown.")
                .that(written)
                .contains("com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImplTest$ProfiledInterfaceImpl");
        assertThat(written).contains("0m 1s 0ms");
    }

    @Test
    public void testServiceLoader() throws Exception {
        Field metadataField = ProfilerImpl.class.getDeclaredField("serviceMetadata");
        metadataField.setAccessible(true);
        Profiler trueProfiler = new ProfilerImpl(clock, true);
        Profiler falseProfiler = new ProfilerImpl(clock, false);

        assertEquals(2, ((Map<Class<?>, ServiceMetadata<?>>) metadataField.get(falseProfiler)).size());
        assertEquals(3, ((Map<Class<?>, ServiceMetadata<?>>) metadataField.get(trueProfiler)).size());
    }

    /**
     * A test interface that does not have any {@link Profiled} methods.
     */
    private interface NonProfiledInterface {
    }

    /**
     * Concrete implementation of {@link NonProfiledInterface}.
     */
    private static final class NonProfiledInterfaceImpl implements NonProfiledInterface {
    }

    /**
     * A test interface that has a method annotated with {@link Profiled}.
     */
    private interface ProfiledInterface {
        @Profiled
        String profiled();

        @Profiled
        void throwSomething(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable;

        boolean equals(String foo, String bar);
    }

    /**
     * Concrete implementation of {@link ProfiledInterface}.
     */
    @Wrapped
    private static final class ProfiledInterfaceImpl implements ProfiledInterface {
        private final FakeClock fakeClock;
        private boolean wasFakeEqualsCalled = false;

        ProfiledInterfaceImpl(FakeClock fakeClock) {
            this.fakeClock = Objects.requireNonNull(fakeClock);
        }

        @Override
        public String profiled() {
            fakeClock.tick(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            return "profiled";
        }

        @Override
        public void throwSomething(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
            fakeClock.tick(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            throw throwable;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            // All instances of ProfiledInterface are equal to one another.
            return (other instanceof ProfiledInterface);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(String foo, String bar) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(foo);
            Objects.requireNonNull(bar);
            wasFakeEqualsCalled = true;
            return false;
        }

        public boolean wasFakeEqualsCalled() {
            return wasFakeEqualsCalled;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception was thrown at the line `private final Profiler profiler = new ProfilerImpl(clock, true);` and I don't know why. Please check the below code:

```
/**
 * Concrete implementation of the {@link Profiler}.
 */
final class ProfilerImpl implements Profiler {
    private final Map<Class<?>, ServiceMetadata<?>> serviceMetadata;
    private final Clock clock;
    private final ProfilingState state = new ProfilingState();
    private final ZonedDateTime startTime;

    @Inject
    ProfilerImpl(Clock clock, boolean includeTest) {
        this.clock = Objects.requireNonNull(clock);
        this.startTime = ZonedDateTime.now(clock);
        ServiceLocator<Class<?>> serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.webCrawlerLocator(includeTest);
        serviceMetadata = serviceLocator.parse(serviceLocator.locateService());
    }

    private ServiceMetadata<?> profiledClass(Class<?> klass) {
        for (Class<?> clazz : serviceMetadata.keySet()) {
            if (klass.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                return serviceMetadata.get(clazz);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T wrap(Class<T> klass, T delegate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(klass);

        ServiceMetadata<?> profiledClass = profiledClass(klass);
        if (profiledClass == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(klass.getName() + "doesn't have profiled methods.");
        }

        ProfilingMethodInterceptor interceptor = new ProfilingMethodInterceptor(clock, delegate, state, startTime, profiledClass);

        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                ProfilerImpl.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{klass},
                interceptor
        );

        return (T) proxy;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(Path path) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(path);

        try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
            writeData(writer);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("Run at " + RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.format(startTime));
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        state.write(writer);
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler.IgnoredUrls
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath$ClassInfo.load(ClassPath.java:360)
        ... 88 more
```

Please help

Comment: Check your dependencies, maybe there is a chance that you have two versions of the same library, where should be this class that is producing error. So maybe when IDEA is compiling code it is taking version of lib without class, and maven is taking correct one

Comment: `target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler.IgnoredUrls` looks like you're confusing package structure with maven file layout.

Comment: Please pull src code on Github and help me to check whether im wrong somewhere

Comment: I cloned your repo, ran `mvn test` (in Eclpse, embedded Maven 3.8.7) and got the same error an other class: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler.json.ConfigurationLoader`: https://gist.github.com/gerib/7dc26411c1195ecfbcc4ff50ff3a7071.

Comment: If I run _JUnit Test_ on `ProfilerImplTest` in Eclipse everything's fine.

Comment: Can it be that the tests (functions) are not completely self-contained so that execution order matters? To rule that out I'd try to use the same [`@Order(n)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Order.html) as they are run in the IDE successfully.

Comment: I tried it. Order doesn't  matter. Since (as @AntonTokmakov above) I'm also irritated by this `target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler` package I ran `mvn test -X`: `[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0:test' with basic configurator`\n`[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = /home/geri/dev/so.eclipse.wksp/so-76420034-java-unit-test/target/classes` looks OK. Then I tried different versions of the Surefire plugin (3.1.2, 3.0.0, 2.22.2), to no avail. ...cont'd...

Comment: Then I ran `mvn test -Dmaven.surefire.debug` in the shell with a conditional breakpoint in Eclipse at `WebCrawlerServiceLocator:55`: `info.getPackageName().startsWith("target")`...and....really, it came to `className: "target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler.json.ConfigurationLoader"`. ...cont'd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the actions in the comments to the question I:

- added `.peek(System.out::println)` prior to (line 52) `filter(classInfo -> ...)` in `WebCrawlerServiceLocator`,
- ran `mvn test -Dmaven.surefire.debug > mvn-test.out` and
- on line 5617 therein there was `target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler.json.ConfigurationLoader` followed by the error mentioned in the question and its comments:

```
...
target.classes.com.udacity.webcrawler.json.ConfigurationLoader
[ERROR] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.84 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImplTest
[ERROR] delegateHasNoMethodsAnnotated  Time elapsed: 0.008 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.udacity.webcrawler.service.ServiceLocator.webCrawlerLocator(ServiceLocator.java:13)
    at com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImpl.<init>(ProfilerImpl.java:34)
    at com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImplTest.<init>(ProfilerImplTest.java:27)
    ...
```

So, apparently [`ImmutableSet<ClassInfo> com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath.getAllClasses()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html#getAllClasses()) takes Maven's `${project.basedir}` as class path entry. The problem is:

- that you can't simply strip `target/classes/` from `packageName` in `map(info -> { ... })` since [`ClassPath.ClassInfo`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.ClassInfo.html) has no setters
- and it has a constructor [`ClassInfo(File file, String resourceName, ClassLoader loader)`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.java#L303) but with default (package) access only.

Anyway, [`ClassPath`'s javadoc](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) mentions at the very beginning:

> ### Prefer [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki) over `ClassPath`

#### UPDATE

Out of curiosity I implemented the usage of *ClassGraph* (which perhaps is even more performant since it has `classInfo.hasAnnotation(...)` which lets you keep only those `ClassInfo`s you're interested in before they are transformed into `Class`es in `map(...)` ):

##### POM

```
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.160</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

#### `WebCrawlerServiceLocator`

```
...
import static java.lang.System.out;
...
import io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph;
...
private static final Class<? extends Annotation> WRAPPED = Wrapped.class;
...
    @Override
    public Collection<Class<?>> locateService() {

        try {
            return new HashSet<>( ClassPath.from( ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() ).getAllClasses().stream()
                    .filter( classInfo -> !classInfo.getName().equals( "module-info" ) || !classInfo.getName().equals( "package-info" ) )
                    //.peek( out::println )
                    .map( classInfo -> {
                        try {

                            //if ( classInfo.getName().contains( "com.udacity" ) )
                            //  out.printf( "--> name: %s%n--> cp: %s%n%n",
                            //      classInfo.getName(), System.getProperty( "java.class.path" ) );

                            return classInfo.load();
                        }
                        catch ( Error | Exception e ) {
                            out.printf( "--> %s --> return null%n", e );
                            return null;
                        }
                    } ) // map(...)
                    //.peek( out::println )
                    .filter( Objects::nonNull )
                    .filter( clazz -> clazz.isAnnotationPresent( WRAPPED ) )
                    .toList() ); // HashSet<>(...)
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            out.printf( "--> %s%n--> return empty list%n", e );
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    public Collection<Class<?>> locateService2() {

        try {
            return new HashSet<Class<?>>(
                    new ClassGraph().enableAllInfo().scan().getAllClasses().stream()
                            .filter( classInfo -> !classInfo.getName().equals( "module-info" ) || !classInfo.getName().equals( "package-info" ) )
                            //.peek( out::println )
                            .filter( classInfo -> classInfo.hasAnnotation( WRAPPED ) )
                            .map( classInfo -> {
                                try {

                                    //if ( classInfo.getName().contains( "com.udacity" ) )
                                    //  out.printf( "--> name: %s%n--> cp: %s%n%n",
                                    //      classInfo.getName(), System.getProperty( "java.class.path" ) );

                                    return classInfo.loadClass();
                                }
                                catch ( Error | Exception e ) {
                                    out.printf( "--> %s --> return null%n", e );
                                    return null;
                                }
                            } ) // map(...
                            //.peek( out::println )
                            .filter( Objects::nonNull )
                            .toList() ); // HashSet<>(...)
        }
        // with IOException compile error: "Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"
        catch ( /*IO*/ Exception e ) {
            out.printf( "--> %s%n--> return empty list%n", e );
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
...
```

BTW, with the `INSTANCE` and `getInstance()` members this class looks like intended to be a Singleton at first sight. But it isn't. Since there's `return new WebCrawlerServiceLocator( true );` in `getInstance()`. That might confuse readers/users of this class (without any Javadoc in addition). I'd complain about that in a code review, about both.

#### `WebCrawlerServiceLocatorTest`

```
package com.udacity.webcrawler.service;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public final class WebCrawlerServiceLocatorTest {

    private static final int CLASS_COUNT = 3;

    @Test
    public void locateServiceWithTest_NotEmpty() {

        ServiceLocator<Class<?>> locator = WebCrawlerServiceLocator.getInstance( true );
        Collection<Class<?>> classes = locator.locateService();
        out.printf( "### locateService(): classes collection contains %d classes: %s %n",
                classes.size(), classes.toString() );
        assertFalse( "classes collection is empty", classes.isEmpty() );
        assertEquals( CLASS_COUNT, classes.size() );
    }

    @Test
    public void locateServiceWithoutTest_NotEmpty() {

        ServiceLocator<Class<?>> locator = WebCrawlerServiceLocator.getInstance( false );
        Collection<Class<?>> classes = locator.locateService();
        out.printf( "### locateService(): classes collection contains %d classes: %s %n",
                classes.size(), classes.toString() );
        assertFalse( "classes collection is empty", classes.isEmpty() );
        assertEquals( CLASS_COUNT, classes.size() );
    }

    @Test
    public void locateServiceWithTest2_NotEmpty() {

        //ServiceLocator<Class<?>> locator = WebCrawlerServiceLocator.getInstance( true ); // compile error
        // ServiceLocator has no locateService2(), hence using the following for the time being:
        WebCrawlerServiceLocator locator = (WebCrawlerServiceLocator) WebCrawlerServiceLocator.getInstance( true );

        Collection<Class<?>> classes = locator.locateService2();
        out.printf( "### locateService2(): classes collection contains %d classes: %s %n",
                classes.size(), classes.toString() );
        assertFalse( "classes collection is empty", classes.isEmpty() );
    }

    @Test
    public void locateServiceWithoutTest2_NotEmpty() {

        //ServiceLocator<Class<?>> locator = WebCrawlerServiceLocator.getInstance( false ); // compile error
        // , ServiceLocator has no locateService2(), hence using the following for the time being:
        WebCrawlerServiceLocator locator = (WebCrawlerServiceLocator) WebCrawlerServiceLocator.getInstance( false );

        Collection<Class<?>> classes = locator.locateService2();
        out.printf( "### locateService2(): classes collection contains %d classes: %s %n",
                classes.size(), classes.toString() );
        assertFalse( "classes collection is empty", classes.isEmpty() );
    }

}
```

#### `mvn test`

```
...
[INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ udacity-webcrawler ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.json.ConfigurationLoaderTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.191 s -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.json.ConfigurationLoaderTest
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.json.CrawlResultWriterTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.021 s -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.json.CrawlResultWriterTest
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.parser.PageParserImplTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.093 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.parser.PageParserImplTest
...
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImplTest
[INFO] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.906 s -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.profiler.ProfilerImplTest
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.service.WebCrawlerServiceLocatorTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.724 s -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.service.WebCrawlerServiceLocatorTest
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.WordCountsTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.WordCountsTest
...
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.ParallelWebCrawlerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.067 s -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.ParallelWebCrawlerTest
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawlerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.013 s -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawlerTest
[INFO] Running com.udacity.webcrawler.WebCrawlerTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 22, Failures: 14, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.221 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.udacity.webcrawler.WebCrawlerTest
...
[ERROR] Tests run: 53, Failures: 18, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
...
```

So, the tests run, at least. They "just" fail due to failing assertions.

And, BTW, I'd not introduce an extra `/src/test/data` dir. I'd use `/src/test/resources` because that's what it is for – Convention over Configuration. Such you can use `AnyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path-relative-to-resources-dir/file.name")` in your tests and avoid having to define `<testDataDir>` in your POM and, more important, to define `-DtestDataDir=...` as VM argument when running unit tests from within your IDE. And you can use [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) (which is string interpolation, in fact), a powerful feature.

If you grant me [access on GitHub](https://github.com/gerib) I can push a branch with all the changes.

### UPDATE

The original `webCrawlerServiceLocator.locateService()` works now, too. I think that's because I declared only the following for JUnit in the POM:

```
    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ...
```

So, it seems that incompatibilities between JUnit dependencies (in a certain version) and Maven's Surefire plugin (in a certain version) might have caused the original issue.

Comment: What is your github username/email?

Comment: @SoT The last link in my answer points to my GL page.

Comment: I added you to my repo

Comment: @SoT Did you give me write access to the repo, too? Because: https://imgur.com/VD2vB5Q.png.

Comment: You have to accept my invitation first (check your email)

Comment: @SoT There's a link "[accept or decline](https://github.com/anaconda875/udacity-webcrawler/invitations)" in the e-mail but I do not see anything like _accept invitation_ when following it....and: https://imgur.com/jnVSa6s.png.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It's so appreciable. Let me do the rest